# hitCallback triggers click on animated sub-nav on touch device

Tags: javascript, ios, google-analytics, touch, google-tag-manager

I have encountered and issue where an sub-menu animated by transitions is not working properly on touch devices. By disabling JavaScript on iOS the sub-menu worked liek a charm so I eliminated script by script. The last one was the Google Tag Manager implementation. So I have eliminated all tags until the last one, the Universal Analytics Tag.

The only function I recognized as a possible cause was [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback). My assumption is that hitCallback does not respect the firing order of touch events as: mouseover, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, and click (Check figure 6.4 by [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7))

Anyway I have not implemented a hitCallback with the Google Tag Manager the function is shown in the console. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks a lot for your support